# Phpunit error in PhpStorm

Tags: phpunit, phpstorm

I am running tests in PhpStorm and I get this error. Does anyone know what on earth could be causing it?

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'PHPUnit_TextUI_ResultPrinter' not found in
>   C:\Users\administrator1\AppData\Local\Temp\ide-phpunit.php on line 249

I run tests in other projects - that also utilise `ide-phpunit.php` and they run just fine.

Comment: PHPUnit version? What kind of installation it is (PHAR/Composer)? PhpStorm version?

Comment: I figured out the issue (answer below). In the interests of helping Googlers that are troubleshooting this issue though it was a composer install, phpunit 3.7, PhpStorm 9 :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Silly mistake on my part... simply forgot to add phpunit as a dependency in the project. For anyone else that gets this error, to composer.json add:

```
"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "3.7.*"
},
```

And then run:

```
composer update
```

That solved the problem.

Comment: Somehow didn't solve the problem, neither with "require" nor with any higher PHPUnit version (5.5)

Comment: I didn't solve my problem neither... 
PHPUnit 6.0.7 with PHP 7.1.2 and PHPStorm 2016.3.2

Comment: Issue with PHPUNIT 6. There is a fix but not merged yet
https://github.com/whatthejeff/nyancat-phpunit-resultprinter/pull/12

Comment: Added  "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.3.3" did the trick :-)

Answer (score 31):

I had the same issue with Ubuntu 16.10, phpStorm 2017.2 and Laravel 5.5

Fixed it by uninstalling phpunit from my Ubuntu-system with

```
sudo apt-get remove phpunit
sudo apt-get install --autoremove
```

or for mac:

```
brew uninstall phpunit
brew install phpunit
```

My PhpStorm configuration (File -> Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> PHP -> Test Frameworks):

[image: phpStorm-Configuration]

Works great, now!

Comment: I had this fix the same issue, with a similar setup.  The only difference was Ubuntu 17.10.

Comment: @panepeter I only have one theory as to why.  For me composer PHPUnit (PU) version was 6.5 and the system version was 5.1  I extended the namespaced version of the TestCase class so PU6 TestCase was autoloaded.  somewhere however a PU6 class uses a class that exists in PU5, which was autoloaded from the system rather than via composer.  I do not have an autoloader for the system version so I can only guess that installing phpunit modified something to include an autoloader for itself which is added before composers version.

Comment: Fixed identical issue on Ubuntu 20.04 with the current PHPStorm 2020. I had been plagued by this for several months on all my TDD projects where I could not use PHPStorm's test runner. It didn't matter how I defined the reference to the PHPUnit executable I would get bizarre errors. Never thought about removing the distro's phpunit.

Answer (score 12):

In my case the problem was caused by following set of reasons:

1. I installed phpunit using composer with `composer require phpunit/phpunit` command. I did not pay attention that by default it used php7 and it installed phpunit6 which has class names with namespaces (`PHPUnit\TextUI\ResultPrinter`).
2. IDE runs old version of phpunit which expects class names without namespaces (`PHPUnit_TextUI_ResultPrinter`)

I decided to reinstall `phpunit` running same composer command as above, but under `php 5.6` (because it was important to be compatible with php5.6) and it installed `phpunit 5.7` . 
But it is possible to go with newer version of phpunit and php: `Settings > PHP > PHPUnit :: "Use composer autoloader"` (set path to phpunit executable inside vendors (it was `vendors/bin/phpunit` in my case))

Comment: I just did a 'refresh' in 'Test Framework Settings' and PhpStorm updated PhpUnit to the latest version - and that helped.

Comment: Yes, this pointed me in the right direction, when updating phpunit in the composer.json, phpstorm config must be reloaded in order to detect the update. Thank you

Answer (score 7):

I got this error while using the various *modifier*-F10 keys in PHPStorm, because it didn't know where to find the correct PHPUnit.

In settings (ctrl-alt-s), search for PHPUnit. In my case I wanted to set it as follows:

- "use composer autoloader"
- Path to script: `full-path-to-project/vendor/autoload.php` (this field was empty for me, with an error showing in the dialog)

Otherwise it would try to use some cached version of the library (`/tmp/ide-phpunit.php`) instead of the composer version. If you prefer to use some globally installed binary, you could of course use the `Path to phpunit.phar` option.

Comment: NB. Use `vendor/autoload.php` not project root's `autoload.php`.

Answer (score 7):

I had same problem with PHP7.1 and PHPUnit 6.3 via composer but I resolved via phpunit.phar. (in the options : select path to phpunit.phar, click on download and click on refresh)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

After updating to latest composer, `composer run-script drupal-phpunit-upgrade`, PHPStorm was still mapped to the old version even though I was loading through autoloader.  I went to Languages & Frameworks > Php > Test Frameworks and hit the refresh button on the same line as "Path to Script".

Now my PHPUnit version reads 6.5.8.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, in phpstorm preferences -> php -> CLI interpreter was set on local, when it needed to use remote php 7 (ubuntu).

Because I use vagrant box to have my environment configured on ubuntu.

Comment: same for docker

Answer (score 0):

I recently came across similar error `PHPUnit_TextUI_ResultPrinter not found in TeamCity.php on line 19`

I am using `PhpStorm 2018.3.3`. Upon using terminal from PhpStorm 
`$ phpunit 
PHPUnit 7.5.1 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.`

from my Ubuntu system 
`$ phpunit --version 
PHPUnit 5.1.3 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.`

**I had to make sure the my Ubuntu system PHPUnit is updated** to 7.5.1. So here's what I did:

```
sudo wget https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit-7.5.1.phar
sudo chmod +x phpunit-7.5.1.phar
sudo mv phpunit-7.5.1.phar /usr/local/bin/phpunit
```

Then I went to PhpStorm:
File > Settings > Language & Frameworks > PHP > Test Frameworks and made sure that the PHPUnit version is also 7.5.1

And then from PhpStorm terminal: `phpunit` and the test cases were running perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

I went to the settings and set my path to php as follows: (according to the brew)

```
/usr/local/opt/php/bin/php
```

Then phpunit works.

Answer (score 0):

I opened the php extension mbstring to solved this problem

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you use a remote CLI Interpreter (e.g. Linux through WSL) as your project default, with the default PHPUnit configuration set to *Local*, you may get that error.

**Add a Remote Interpreter PHPUnit configuration instead.**

Go to (PHPStorm settings) -> PHP -> Test Frameworks

[image: PHPStorm Remote Interpreter config]

[image: Add new PHPStorm Remote Interpreter config]

I got the error with PHP 8.2 + PHPUnit 10 + PHPStorm 2023.1.2

Answer (score -4):

I got the same error. Solved by using phpunit4.8 (older version)

Comment: because there are several better solutions above, downgrading phpunit should not be considered an acceptable solution.  In my experience this issue happens when you have more than 1 phpunit version (one system, one composer vendor).  downgrading one would only work if by chance it made the 2 versions compatible with each other.